# Interpretación resultados Conover test (conover.test) en R

Tags: r

Soy nueva en el uso del lenguaje de programación R y he intentado con éste hacer un Kruskal Wallis y luego un Conover test (con corrección de Holm) usando datos de 6 especies de peces, 6 estaciones (bueno, 4 de un año y dos del siguiente) de muestreo, diferente número de muestras (entre 25 y 140 réplicas por estacion) entre estaciones y la naturaleza de los datos es de número de animales presentes en un determinado espacio. Mis muestras no son ni normales ni homocedásticas (he intentado las transformaciones tipo log y raíz cuadrada, X^2 e inversa sin éxito). Quiero saber qué estaciones son diferentes de qué estaciones para cada una de las especies. Uno esperaría ver que el conover test guarda relación con la serie temporal de los animales pero para nada. Alguien me puede decir dónde está el error?

## Ejemplo del script de una especie, *Anoploma fimbria*:

```
#Importing data from tab delimited file (replace stars with an appropriate 
object name e.g.,Anoplopoma_fimbria.krustal.wallis) 
Anoplopoma_fimbria.seasons.krustal.wallis <-read.table(file.choose(), header=T)
names(Anoplopoma_fimbria.seasons.krustal.wallis)
str(Anoplopoma_fimbria.seasons.krustal.wallis)
estaciones <- as.character(Anoplopoma_fimbria.seasons.krustal.wallis$seasons)
str(estaciones)
library("conover.test", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")
conover.test(Anoplopoma_fimbria.seasons.krustal.wallis$counts, g=estaciones, wrap=TRUE, method="holm", kw=TRUE, alpha = 0.01)
```

## Aquí el resultado que me ha dado el conover test (y el kruskal wallis lo pongo por contextualizar). No consigo que el formato de la tabla se vea bien al subirlo aquí así que hice un pantallazo, aquí lo tienen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

## Dejo una imagen de la serie temporal del animal con el que dió estos resultados. El eje X está en meses por algo que ahora no procede explicar. Empieza con Febrero del 2013 y de allí en adelante.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No consigo que el formato de la tabla se vea bien al subirlo aquí así que hice un pantallazo, aquí lo tienen: Lo que usted puede hacer es seleccionar el texto, como en cualquier editor despues con este selecionado puede pulsar ctrl+k o en el panel de edicion puede ver { } en la parte superior, haciendo click puede aplicar ese formato y a la inversa para quitarlo, en un pregunta suya en la que añadia una tabla hice algo similar puede verla y probar con ella para poner y quitar el formato

Comment: -> http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/5920/significant-kruskal-test-but-not-significant-dunn-test en la parte inferior de la pregunta puede ver editar haga click para ello espero ayude. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias Angel, de todos modos creo que se aprecia bien el resultado con esta imagen no?

Comment: si se aprecia bien, pero como usted comentaba "No consigo..." le deje la forma en la que podia lograrlo.No solo sirve para lo de formatear una table, lo puede usar para formatear las partes de codigo que quiera poner en alguna pregunta/respuesta por ejemplo. Saludos

Comment: Para futuras referencias, te sugiero que publiques tu pregunta en https://stats.stackexchange.com/ que es el sitio de la comunidad en el cual se abordan dudas relacionadas con la modelación y la interpretación estadística. Saludos :)